# Can a Wizard tell which Alarm spell was tripped?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

It has already been established that a wizard can have as many Alarm spells active as they have time and materials for. My question is can he tell which spell was triggered in the case of multiple simultaneous spells?

Comment: Which game are you playing? We can't tell if it's Pathfinder, or one of the D&D editions... or something else entirely.